# Tail proxychains socks5 proxy timeout

Tags: tails

I'm trying to use proxychain on tails.

So first I can't use iceweasel with proxychains. I get the error :

> /usr/bin/proxychains: 9: exec: iceweasel: notfound

So I use tor-browser instead.
But when I try to use the socks5 proxy I get a timeout on iceweasel.

When I configure the proxy directly in the the config panel of tor-browser I says that the server  is refusing connections.

The proxy is working perfectly on firefox on windows and tor browser on windows.

**EDIT :**

I've tried to setup proxychains on a kali distrib.
When I use tor alone, it works.
When I use my socks5 server (dante-server) alone, it works.
But when I use both, the connection just get denied :

> |S-chain| -<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<--denied

I ssh connect to my socks5 server with :

> ssh -NfD 1080 user@address.com

And in my proxychains.conf :

> #dynamic_chain 
>   strict_chain 
>   proxy_dns 
>   tcp_read_time_out 15000 
>   tcp_connect_time_out 8000 
>   #For tor 
>   socks4 127.0.0.1 9050 
>   #Proxy server 
>   socks5 127.0.0.1 1080

**EDIT 2 :** Apparently it could be a problem of my dante's configuration

So I tried to allow connections from any IP address in dante, I'm not sure if it's right :

```
logoutput: /var/log/dante.log

internal: 127.0.0.1 port = 1080
external: venet0
method: username none
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  protocol: tcp udp
}
pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  protocol: tcp udp
}
```

But it's still not working

Comment: I've got same problem did you sort this out?

Comment: Yes I've explained everything [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168305/91384)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of setup will not work, consider what you're asking proxychains to do: Connect to the local Tor SOCKS port then ask Tor to make a connection to a localhost address.

No amount of reconfiguration will work, you'd be asking an exit to connect to 127.0.0.1, which from its perspective is itself, not your own localhost where the proxy is listening. Exit will, by default, reject connection attempts to private and local addresses.